# Mix node to limit value

Tags: materials, node-editor

Can anyone figure out why a mix node with black and white was used in conjunction with the minimum and maximum nodes of this node group? The purpose of the two math nodes (with minimum and maximum) is to limit the input value (in the upper input of the Mininum node) to a smaller range.

Currently the maximum and minimum are set by changing the Fac(tor) input of the mix nodes. However, in my head the result should be the same if I simply control the value by the lower input of the math node?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some more experimentation, the only explanation I can find is that the author of the node group wished the input to be a slider instead of simply a value. Perhaps this makes sense, since the values should be between zero to one.

Does anyone else find some other explanation?

Comment: It seems like that's their way of fashioning a handle for the node group.